# Best practice - should I initialize object before using it on form?

Tags: angularjs

For instance, I have a form to edit "user" object, that has properties like "name", "password", etc. I can initialize "user" in a controller like `$scope.user = {}` beforehand. But even if won't, as soon as I enter a value into `<input ng-model="user.name"/>`, the "user" object will be initialized, so theoretically the initialization is not needed unless I want to have some predefined values. Though it feels wrong that your code uses the variable that can't be found in the controller.

What is considered the best practice for this case?

Comment: Isn't that the purpose of angularjs -- two way data binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you initialise it in the controller for clarity's sake. Then any developer coming along can see what is going on. Of course, if you want some default values then controller initialisation makes total sense.